# SQL returning figures instead of months

Tags: sql

I was wondering if you could help me with this question.
I have been asked to (within the database) to return the months June and August but not in letters but in figures so as shown below with the code, June should be 06 and so forth. I know this piece of code is incorrect, if you could direct in the right way I would really appreciate your help. Thank You

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Departments
    (
        First_Name        NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        Last_Name         NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        Job_Description   VARCHAR(30)  NULL,
        Department_Name   VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
        Department_Number INT          NOT NULL,
        Date_Hired        DATE         NOT NULL,
    );

INSERT INTO dbo.Departments(First_Name,Last_Name,Job_Description,Department_Name,Department_Number,Date_Hired)
VALUES
('Niel','Matthews','Sales Representative','Marketing',80,'1990-06-12'),
('Jerome','Daniels','Sales Representative','Accounting',60,'1973-03-30'),
('Caleb','Sewcharran','Employee','Accounting',35,'1986-08-10'),
('Orion','Wolf','Employee','Marketing',80,'1987-10-04'),
('Gaige','Johnson','Employee','Accounting',60,'1992-09-22'),
('Maya','Heller','Employee','Marketing',25,'1989-06-17'),
('James','Maroon','Employee','Accounting',30,'2011-08-22'),
('Alex','Mercer','Employee','Accounting',60,'2010-03-17'),
('Adam','Beecher','Sales Representative','Marketing',80,'2012-10-04'),
('Bruce','Wayne','Employee','Marketing',25,'2012-08-12'),
('Al','Kepler','Sales Representative','Accounting',80,'1973-06-30');

SELECT First_Name,Last_Name,
(SELECT Date_Hired,
(SELECT CASE
    WHEN Date_Hired=06
    THEN 'June'
    WHEN Date_Hired=08
    THEN 'August'
    END))
    FROM dbo.Departments 
ORDER BY Last_Name;
```

> (Error Message)
>   Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 179
>   Operand type clash: date is incompatible with tinyint
>   Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 187
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS
>   (Also can you explain to me why this message has occurred)

Comment: Ok, so first question, you say you know this code is incorrect, can you tell us the schema and the desired result that you need to query.

Comment: What type is the `Date_Hired` column and can you show us some sample data?

Comment: You cannot use SELECT as a column.

Comment: Sample data and desire results would really help.

Comment: @CalebSewcharran  I have edited my answer to give you a more precise response.

Comment: @mentallurg: of course you can (if the select returns one row and one column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select month by number of name then take a look at this code and this should get you on the right track.

I cant give you exact SQL because you state in your question that you know the SQL is incorrect.

```
SELECT 
MONTH([yourdatefieldName]) AS [Month Number], 
DATENAME(MM, [yourdatefieldName]) AS [Month Name]
FROM myTable
WHERE yourclauseshere
```

------------------Edit---------------------------

Now that you have edited your question a better SQL Code block would be something like this.

```
SELECT
First_Name,
Last_Name,
Date_Hired,
DATENAME(MM, Date_Hired) AS [Month]
FROM
dbo.Departments
WHERE DATENAME(MM, Date_Hired) IN ('June', 'August')
```

Rather than have it as a case statement you'll be better off using it in the where clause.

There are obviously other ways of doing it but this is how I would do it in the way that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms) you were using, but from the use of `dbo` and from the error message it seems to be [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). If this is indeed the case, you could just use [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of reinventing the wheel:

```
SELECT   First_Name, Last_Name, FORMAT(Date_Hired, 'MM')
FROM     dbo.Departments 
ORDER BY Last_Name
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the question in the comments, you can use functions calls like this in the `where` clause too:

```
SELECT   First_Name, Last_Name, FORMAT(Date_Hired, 'MM')
FROM     dbo.Departments 
WHERE    FORMAT(Date_Hired, 'MM') = '06'
ORDER BY Last_Name
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a where clause to this batch,i have edited my above question with sample data. I would like to add a where clause like for e.g.  WHERE Date_Hired =06;